# Android: Why does getDimension and getDimensionPixelSize both return the same?

Tags: android, android-resources

I find the methods getDimension and getDimensionPixelSize confusing.

It would look to me as though getDimension would return the actual value stored in the dimension, for example 10dp and getDimensionPixelSize would return it converted to px.

But both seem to do the same thing...

Comment: Maybe the device screen density is mdpi? Then they will be the same.

Comment: It's a very good question. I also wondered about that. The documentation of [getDimension](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDimension%28int%29) is actually suboptimal because the formulation and naming is a bit unclear and it is not clear which unit the output is actually. Thanks for this question.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

[`getDimension()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDimension(int)) returns a floating point number which is the dimen value adjusted with current display metrics:

[`getDimensionPixelSize()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDimensionPixelSize(int)) returns an integer. It is the same as `getDimension()` rounded to an `int` with any non-zero dimension ensured to be at least one pixel in size.

For integer dimension values they both return the same numeric value.

Comment: I wonder what "adjusted with current display metrics" really means?

Comment: @Trilarion It mostly means that for values that are specified in `dp`, they will be converted to pixels based on the density of the screen. For instance, a dimension of `5dp` for an `xhdpi` screen would actually be returned as 10 (pixels). Similarly for values in `sp` and etc. (although the actual formula will differ for each)

Answer (score 2):

It seems obvious to me that you are doing your tests on an **mdpi** device or emulator.
On **mdpi** displays, **1px = 1dp**.

So, simply test the methods on a **different density** screen.

---

Note that

```
public float getDimension (int id)

Retrieve a dimensional for a particular resource ID.  
Unit conversions are based on the current DisplayMetrics associated with the resources.

Parameters  
id  The desired resource identifier, as generated by the aapt tool.  
This integer encodes the package, type, and resource entry. The value 0 is an invalid identifier.

Returns  
Resource dimension value multiplied by the appropriate metric.
```

So, if you set the unit in px in your xml layout, you will get the crude px (unconverted).
Otherwise, if you correctly set the unit in dp in your xml layout, you will get the proper conversion to px.

Comment: Not converted to dp but dp converted to px. I tested on a different density device and getDimension returns a scaled value.

Comment: Right. Corrected my answer.

Comment: I think the official documentation could be improved here. What is "a dimensional"? What does "is based on..." mean? Why can't they simply say that they convert to pixel using the DisplayMetrics?

Comment: Because that would make the official documentation actually useful.